# BeautifulSoup to get 'span' contents next to each other

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

A part of HTML looks like below. I want to extract the contents in the 'span' tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = """
<section><h2>Team</h2><ul><li><ul><li><span>J36</span>—<span>John</span></li><li><span>B56</span>—<span>Bratt</span></li><li><span>K3</span>—<span>Kate</span></li></ul></li></ul></section>
... """
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

classification = soup.find_all('section')[0].find_all('span')

for c in classification:
    print (c.text)
```

It works out:

```
J36
John
B56
Bratt
K3
Kate
```

But the wanted:

```
J36-John
B56-Bratt
K3-Kate
```

What's the proper BeautifulSoup way to extract the contents, other than below?

```
contents = [c.text for c in classification]

l = contents[0::2]
ll = contents[1::2]

for a in zip(l, ll):
    print ('-'.join(a))
```

Comment: If you don't mind using regex instead,  `rows = [''.join(x) for x in re.findall('<span>([A-Z0-9]+?)</span>(—)<span>([A-Za-z]+?)</span>', data)]` `print('\n'.join(rows))`

Comment: @alec, thank you. it's a html file saved to local. So I tried: HtmlFile = open("C:\\file.html", 'r', encoding='utf-8'); source_code = HtmlFile.read(). Then applied your line with the "source_code" . it doesn't work out...

Comment: Maybe it's the type of dash that is not matching, since the dash in `data` (—) and the dashes in the output (-) are different. See if this works `rows = ['-'.join(x) for x in re.findall('<span>([A-Z0-9]+?)</span>.*?<span>([A-Za-z]+?)</span>', source_code)]`. Otherwise I'm not sure it could be anything that differs in the file from `data`.

Comment: @alec,the html file has many other tags including other <section>s, so it still not the right output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the next sibling tag. If it's the dash, it will be printed along with the text, otherwise just the text will be printed .

```
for c in classification:
    if c.next_sibling:
        print(c.text + str(c.next_sibling), end='')
    else:
        print(c.text)
```